# simple "identifier 'xxx' is undefined" using a struct

Tags: c++, struct, identifier

I'm barely starting a new project, and I'm unable to simply print a batch of struct data, because of this error. Code is as follows:

Header file:

```
#ifndef EuropeanOption_HPP
#define EuropeanOption_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;    

struct EquityParms
{
    double T; // years until expiry
    double K; // strike price
    double sig; // vol
    double r; // risk free rate
    double S; // current equity price
};

class EuropeanOption
{
private:
    void init(const struct EquityParms data); // initialize EquityParms 

public:

};


#ifndef EUROPEANOPTION_CPP
#include "EuropeanOption.cpp"
#endif

#endif
```

Source file:

```
#ifndef EUROPEANOPTION_CPP
#define EUROPEANOPTION_CPP

#include "EuropeanOption_H.hpp"


void EuropeanOption::init(const struct EquityParms data)
{
    cout << "Years until expiry: \t" << data.T << endl;
    cout << "Strike price: \t" << data.K << endl;
    cout << "Volatility: \t" << data.sig << endl;
    cout << "Risk-free rate: \t" << data.r << endl;
    cout << "Current equity price: \t" << data.S << endl;
}

#endif
```

Test file:

```
#include "EuropeanOption_H.hpp"

int main()
{

    struct EquityParms batch1 = {0.25, 65, 0.30, 0.08, 60};
    struct EquityParms batch2 = {1, 100, 0.2, 0.0, 100};
    struct EquityParms batch3 = {1, 10, 0.5, 0.12, 5};
    struct EquityParms batch4 = {30, 100, 0.30, 0.08, 100};

    init(batch1); // error on this line, "identifier init is undefined"

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler error if I try to build is:
"test.cpp(22): error C3861: 'init': identifier not found"

This is literally 100% of my code. My #includes are there. I tried simply naming it something more unique to no avail. I don't get it... Could you see what's my error here?

Thanks!

Comment: The way you're trying to use it suggests you want it to be static. That aside, typically you wouldn't include the cpp file from the header, you'd link to it.

Comment: Give the variables meaningful names, not just letters.

Comment: Why are you including the source file?

Comment: Suggestion: Also you probably wanted to pass by reference `(const EquityParams& data)` not `(const struct EquityParams data)` (this also isn't C).

Comment: @YochaiTimmer The letters are meaningful in options formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`init()` is a member of a class (and it is `private` so it is not accessible anyway).  `main()` is not a member of that class.  There is no `init()` function in the global scope, either.  That is why the compiler complaints about `init()` being undefined - it really is.  There is no defined `init()` function within `main()`'s scope.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `init` is a method of class `EuropeanOption`, so you can call it from such object. The second fact is that this method is `private` so it's impossible to call it outside the class. And thirdly, you have to use constructor to create objects. Read some c++ books to understand it.